# Circle won't change number of vertices

Tags: vertices, transforms

I finally saw the little box in the bottom left corner that lets me change the number of vertices on a newly added circle, but whenever I change the number, the flat circle that I have made no other changes to spontaneously turns into a cube. What is this, and why is it preventing me from making a simple octagon?